# Replace whole string if it contains substring in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace all strings that contain a specific substring. So for example if I have this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'], 
                   'sport': ['tennis', 'football', 'basketball']})
```

I could replace football with the string 'ball sport' like this:

```
df.replace({'sport': {'football': 'ball sport'}})
```

What I want though is to replace everything that contains `ball` (in this case `football` and `basketball`) with 'ball sport'. Something like this:

```
df.replace({'sport': {'[strings that contain ball]': 'ball sport'}})
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains) to mask the rows that contain 'ball' and then overwrite with the new value:

```
In [71]:
df.loc[df['sport'].str.contains('ball'), 'sport'] = 'ball sport'
df

Out[71]:
    name       sport
0    Bob      tennis
1   Jane  ball sport
2  Alice  ball sport
```

To make it case-insensitive pass `case=False:

```
df.loc[df['sport'].str.contains('ball', case=False), 'sport'] = 'ball sport'
```

Comment: `.contains` also accepts regex, so you could add the case-insensitive flag to the string instead of passing `case=False`, like: `.str.contains(r'(?i)ball')`.

Answer (score 23):

You can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with a lambda. The `x` parameter of the lambda function will be each value in the 'sport' column:

```
df.sport = df.sport.apply(lambda x: 'ball sport' if 'ball' in x else x)
```

Answer (score 15):

you can use `str.replace`

```
df.sport.str.replace(r'(^.*ball.*$)', 'ball sport')

0        tennis
1    ball sport
2    ball sport
Name: sport, dtype: object
```

reassign with

```
df['sport'] = df.sport.str.replace(r'(^.*ball.*$)', 'ball sport')
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A different `str.contains`

```
 df['support'][df.name.str.contains('ball')] = 'ball support'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda function also:

```
data  = {"number": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "function": ['IT', 'IT application', 
'IT digital', 'other', 'Digital'] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
df.function = df.function.apply(lambda x: 'IT' if 'IT' in x else x)
```