# Pandas dataframe replace string in multiple columns by finding substring

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a very large pandas data frame containing both string and integer columns. I'd like to search the whole data frame for a specific substring, and if found, replace the full string with something else.

I've found some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768547/replace-whole-string-if-it-contains-substring-in-pandas) that do this by specifying the column(s) to search, like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'A'], [2,'(B,D,E)'], [3,'C']],columns=['Question','Answer'])
df.loc[df['Answer'].str.contains(','), 'Answer'] = 'X'
```

But because my data frame has dozens of string columns in no particular order, I don't want to specify them all. As far as I can tell using [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) will not work since I'm only searching for a substring. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use data frame `replace` method with `regex=True`, and use `.*,.*` to match strings that contain a comma (you can replace *comma* with other any other substring you want to detect):

```
str_cols = ['Answer']    # specify columns you want to replace
df[str_cols] = df[str_cols].replace('.*,.*', 'X', regex=True)
df
#Question   Answer
#0      1       A
#1      2       X
#2      3       C
```

or if you want to replace all string columns:

```
str_cols = df.select_dtypes(['object']).columns
```