# Extract numbers from strings in python

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, floating-point

I want to extract numbers from strings like. They appear in many columns so what is the most efficient way to remove these strings and get only the numbers? Is there a way other than using regex

Comment: Add the sample output.

Comment: Its always important to add 3 simple things in your question. 1st- Samples of input, 2nd- Samples of output and 3rd- your efforts in form of code, kindly do add these in your question to make it clear, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks for letting me know. I've added sample input and outputs.

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh Thanks for letting me know. I've added them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you expect only one number per column, you could try using `str.extract` here:

```
df["some_col"] = df["some_col"].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')
```

Comment: Hi Tim, What if I have 32 columns that need to be modified like this? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: @Ilovenoodles Reference [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46623596/pandas-dataframe-replace-string-in-multiple-columns-by-finding-substring).  You may use `str.extract` on multiple columns, by passing a list of columns.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a function with regex that matches the pattern of what you are seeing. Since you tagged pandas and dataframe I am assuming you are working with a dataframe but a sample output would certainly help. Here is how I would tackle it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

def extract_numbers (column1: str):
  result = np.nan
  for x in column1.split():
    if re.search(r'\d+\.?\d+', x)
      result = float(re.search(r'\d+\.?\d+', x).group())

    if pd.notnunll(result):
      return result

df['Numbers'] = df['YourColumn'].apply(extract_numbers)
```

The result of this function would be a new column called "Numbers" that contains the extracted number from each string. It will return NaN when a number is not found (or matched to). Once you have a column with the number value from each string you can interact with it however you please.