# Replace whole string if it contains substring in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an sample dataset.

```
raw_data = {
    'categories': ['sweet beverage', 'salty snacks', 'beverage,sweet', 'fruit juice,beverage,', 'salty crackers'],
    'product_name': ['coca-cola', 'salted pistachios', 'fruit juice', 'lemon tea', 'roasted peanuts']}
df_a = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
```

I need to iterate thru the rows in the 'categories' columns, and check if it contains a particular string, in this case, 'beverage', after which i will update the categories to just 'beverage'. This link is the closest i found on stackoverflow, but doesnt tell me how to go thru the whole dataset.

[Replace whole string if it contains substring in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768547/replace-whole-string-if-it-contains-substring-in-pandas)

Here's my sample code.

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if row.str.contains('beverage', na=False):
        df.loc[index,'categories_en'] = 'Beverages' 
    elif row.str.contains('salty',na=False):
        df.loc[index,'categories_en'] = 'Salty Snack'
     ....<and other conditions>
```

How can I achive this? Thanks all!

Comment: Why do you call it "the `categories` column**s**" when it is actually just a single column in the dataframe?

Answer (score 3):

Create following dicts , then using `replace`

```
Yourdict2={1:'Beverages',2:'salty'}
Yourdict1={'beverage':1,'salty':2}
df_a.categories.replace(Yourdict1,regex=True).map(Yourdict2)
Out[275]: 
0    Beverages
1        salty
2    Beverages
3    Beverages
4        salty
Name: categories, dtype: object
```

Comment: This is interesting

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
df_a.loc[df_a.categories.str.contains('beverage'), 'categories'] = 'beverage'


    categories      product_name
0   beverage        coca-cola
1   salty snacks    salted pistachios
2   beverage        fruit juice
3   beverage        lemon tea
4   salty crackers  roasted peanuts
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. I tried to create a function     def transformCat(s) so it will check for other strings. Within the function, i have for example, s=df.loc[df.categories_en.str.lower().str.contains('milk',na=False)] ='Dairies,Milks'
return s When I call my function, df['my_categories'] =df.categories_en.apply(transformCat)    Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `__contains__()` method of Pythons string class:

```
for a in df_a["categories"]:
if a.__contains__("beverage"):
    df_a["categories"].replace(a, "beverage", inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
def selector(x):
    if 'beverage' in x:
        return 'Beverages'
    if 'salty' in x:
        return 'Salty snack'

df_a['categories_en'] = df_a['categories'].apply(selector)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply` to generate a new `categories` column. Then assign it to the `categories_en` column of the dataframe.

```
def map_categories(cat: str) -> str:
    if cat.find("beverage") != -1:
        return "beverage"
    else:
        return str
new_col = df['categories'].apply(map_categories)
df['categories_en'] = new_col
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the various solutions to my question. Based on all your inputs, I have come up with this solution, which works.

```
def transformCat(df):

df.loc[df.categories_en.str.lower().str.contains('beers|largers|wines|rotwein|biere',na=False)] = 'Alcoholic,Beverages'
df.loc[df.categories_en.str.lower().str.contains('cheese',na=False)] = 'Dairies,Cheeses'
df.loc[df.categories_en.str.lower().str.contains('yogurts',na=False)] = 'Dairies,Yogurts'
df.loc[df.categories_en.str.lower().str.contains(r'sauce.*ketchup|ketchup.*sauce',na=False)] = 'Sauces,Ketchups'
```

Would appreciate any inputs. Thanks all!

PS - I am aware there should be an indent beginning at df.loc, but since i am new to stackoverflow (i will learn, i promise), somehow I cant get the indentation correct.